# Change the name/id of an instance already created

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, instance

I have a problem with CKEditor instances name because i had created a lot of ckeditor instance associated witht a textarea so that the ckeditor takes the name of the textarea associated but the problem is when i change the name of a textarea the name of the ckeditor associated dont change and when i make a "getdata " on the new name of textarea my program cannot make the link with the ckeditor initially attached to this textarea which the name had changed ...
So i guess i have to change in same time as i change the textarea id/name the name/id of the ckeditor but i dont find which method can i use to do that in the documentation.. her is my code ..

```
$(".zone_fieldset").each(function(i) { 
nb = i+1;   
$(this).children('textarea').attr('id','desc_etape'+nb);         
$(this).children('textarea').attr('name','desc_etape'+nb)‌​; //// here i want to actualise name/id of 
the ckeditor which replaced the textarea before but i dont find any function to do this 
}); }
```

anyone has an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide relevant code that you are working on

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)